# Access VBA to Change an Image in a Continuous Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a receipt form where people will confirm if they've received the full quantity of an order. As part of this, I want the following to happen:

1. If they received the full quantity, a green check mark appears
2. If they received a partial quantity, an orange triangle appears
3. If they received no items, a red `x` appears

To accomplish this, I'm using a continuous form with 3 image files for each situation. I'm using the code below to change the image when the quantity is changed. The problem is, when the quantity is change on 1 line, the symbol changes for all lines. I'll post pictures as well.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

I'm open to other methods of accomplishing this idea too.

```
Private Sub FinalQTY_AfterUpdate()

If IsNull(Me.FinalQty) Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a quantity for this item"
    Me.FinalQty.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
Else
    LValue = Me.[FinalQty]
    If IsNumeric(LValue) = 0 Then
    Me.FinalQty = ""
    MsgBox "Qty must be a numeric value"
    Me.QTY.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Me.FinalTotalPrice = Me.FinalPrice * Me.FinalQty

If Me.FinalQty = 0 Then
    Me.Yes.Visible = False
    Me.Change.Visible = False
    Me.No.Visible = True
End If

If Me.FinalQty < Me.QTY Then
    Me.Yes.Visible = False
    Me.Change.Visible = True
    Me.No.Visible = False
End If

If Me.FinalQty = Me.QTY Then
    Me.Yes.Visible = True
    Me.Change.Visible = False
    Me.No.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

This is before I adjust the quantity:

[image: This is before I adjust the qty]

This is after I adjust the qty of only the second line:

[image: This is after I adjust the qty of only the second line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the formatting of each record displayed by a continuous form is inherited from the form design template, any changes to the template will be automatically applied to all records displayed by the form, aside from Conditional Formatting rules in effect or the handful of properties which may changed via the `OnPaint` event of the Detail section.

One possible alternative might be to add a new field to your table with a data type of OLE Object and populate the value on the `AfterUpdate` event using the [`AppendChunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/field-appendchunk-method-dao) method, sourcing image data from a separate table containing three records corresponding to your green tick, orange triangle, and red cross images.

Comment: Lee Mac, 

Brilliant idea! I actually did a twist on it to save file space. I'm not actually using the OLE Object, I am referencing the file location in the code and it works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lowendz113 You're most welcome! Feel free to mark my answer as the accepted solution if it sufficient answered your question, thanks!

Comment: That's totally a thing I know how to do... Is it just the green tick?

Comment: @Lowendz113 You got it :)